# To view all the tables in a database server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anyone please help me with the query to list all the tables in all the databases in a single server?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: select * from information_schema.tables

Comment: Gives the tables of current database only., not all databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS stated [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/61855/33311)  by

Try with dynamic query

You need a query for each database against `sys.tables`.

```sql
select 'master' as DatabaseName, 
       T.name collate database_default as TableName 
from master.sys.tables as T 
union all 
select 'tempdb' as DatabaseName, 
       T.name collate database_default as TableName 
from tempdb.sys.tables as T 
union all 
select 'model' as DatabaseName, 
       T.name collate database_default as TableName 
from model.sys.tables as T 
union all 
select 'msdb' as DatabaseName, 
       T.name collate database_default as TableName 
from msdb.sys.tables as T
```

You can use `sys.databases` to build and execute the query dynamically.

```sql
declare @SQL nvarchar(max)

set @SQL = (select 'union all 
select '''+D.name+''' as DatabaseName,
       T.name collate database_default as TableName
from '+quotename(D.name)+'.sys.tables as T
'
from sys.databases as D
for xml path(''), type).value('substring((./text())[1], 13)', 'nvarchar(max)')

--print @SQL
exec (@SQL)
```

Comment: The second query gives the answer. The first query lists the tables of system databases only, while, the second one lists the tables of all databases in a server.

Answer (score 3):

Use `sp_MSforeachdb` to iterate through all databases and `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` to query the tables in each:

```
sp_MSforeachdb 'USE [?]; SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES'
```

Comment: It will return only current database

Comment: This is correct, however a word of caution, `sp_MSforeachdb` is an undocumented procedure and its usage may break in any future release of SQL Server.

Comment: It's not meant for production code. It's for situations when you are exploring an unfamiliar server and want to quickly learn about its objects

Answer (score 0):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#tbl') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #tbl

CREATE TABLE #tbl (
      database_id SYSNAME
    , tbl_name SYSNAME
    , sch_name SYSNAME
    , [rows] INT
)

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @SQL = STUFF((
    SELECT '
    USE [' + d.name + ']
    INSERT INTO #tbl
    SELECT DB_NAME(), o.name, s.name, p.[rows]
    FROM sys.objects o
    JOIN sys.schemas s ON o.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT p.[object_id], [rows] = SUM(p.[rows])
        FROM sys.partitions p
        WHERE p.index_id < 2
        GROUP BY p.[object_id]
    ) p ON p.[object_id] = o.[object_id]
    WHERE o.[type] = ''U''
        AND o.is_ms_shipped = 0;'
    FROM sys.databases d
    WHERE d.[state] = 0
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL

SELECT * FROM #tbl
```